# Is $\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty \mathcal{A}_i$ necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{A}_1 \subset \mathcal{A}_2 \subset \ldots$ are $\sigma$-algebras consisting of subsets of a set $X$. Is $\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty \mathcal{A}_i$ necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra? If not, what is a counterexample?